# Traffic-shaping Application with GUI

Tags: bandwidth

is there any free traffic shaping software for internet gateways with GUI for managing per user/computer bandwidth?

At least it should able to manage per source IP (or MAC), or if possible with user authentication before they can access the internet (captive portal)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/).

> pfSense is a free, open source customized distribution of FreeBSD tailored for use as a firewall and router. In addition to being a powerful, flexible firewalling and routing platform, it includes a long list of related features and a package system …

Answer (score 1):

If you need a professional shaper, etinc is the gold standard. pfsense doesnt scale well and it doesn't actually do window shaping. It just delays packets. The ET/BWMGR pays for itself because it reduces traffic flows so you can put more users with less bandwidth.

www.etinc.com